# jQuery </div> tag causes NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a form that allows visitors to add new form fields using an "add another" link.  It all works great but I'm trying to also get the form to include an "is this field required" checkbox and to do so I need to add some additional divs and that's where I'm running into a problem.  Here's my code:

```
    if (requiredbox) {
        var openPrimary = '<div class="form-item-primary">';
        var closePrimary = '</div>';
        var openSecondary = '<div class="form-item-secondary">\
            <label class="box" for="' + fieldname + '_' + counter + '_required">' + fieldlabel + ' #' + counter + ' Required</label>\
            <input id="' + fieldname + '_' + counter + '_required" class="box" type="checkbox" value="yes" name="' + fieldname + '_' + counter + '_required">\
            <span id="' + fieldname + '_' + counter + '_required" class="forminfo"></span>\
            </div>';
        var closeSecondary = '</div>';
    }
    else {
        var openPrimary = '';
        var closePrimary = '';
        var openSecondary = '';
        var closeSecondary = '';
    }
    $('<div class="form-item">\
    ' + openPrimary + '\
    <label for="' + fieldname + '_' + counter + '">' + fieldlabel + ' #' + counter + '&nbsp;<a href="" class="remove rem_' + counter + '" id="rem' + fieldname + '">(Remove)</a></label>\
    <select id="' + fieldname + '_' + counter + '" name="' + fieldname + '_' + counter + '"' + addJS + '>\
    <option value="">Please Select</option>\
    ' + optionlist + '\
    </select>\
    ' + closePrimary + '\
    ' + openSecondary + '\
    ' + closeSecondary + '\
    </div>').fadeIn("slow").appendTo('#' + fieldname + '_additions');       
    $('input#' + fieldname + '_count').val(counter);
    // Hide the "remove" link on the previous item (if applicable)
    if (counter > mincounter) {
        $('.rem_' + (counter - 1)).hide();
    }
```

The error that I'm getting is Timestamp: 12/5/2012 10:47:10 AM
Error: NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]
Source File: http://mysite.com/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js
Line: 6812

Line 6812 is:
    computed = window.getComputedStyle( elem, null ),

I've narrowed down the problem to the line:

```
var closePrimary = '</div>';
```

If I change the closing div to ANYTHING else it works fine but I need that closing div tag for the layout, of course.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe not related, but you are calling fadeIn on an element that isn't attatched to the dom. Try attaching it first. `.appendTo('#' + fieldname + '_additions').fadeIn("slow")`

Comment: Multi-line strings can be dangerous in JavaScript.

Comment: perhaps a templating engine would help?

Comment: Can you generate your string as a separate variable and then output that (e.g. using `alert()`) to see what it looks like?

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to be with the code you've posted. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/F3nvg/

Comment: @Shmiddty, running that jsfiddle in Firefox produces the error that the OP reported.

Comment: Ah, so it's something with Firefox specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating your HTML fragment as a separate string, using `alert()` to echo it, and pasting the result into the W3 validator gives the following error:

> **end tag for element "DIV" which is not open**

In other words, you have a spurious `</div>` closing tag in `var openSecondary = ...`

Incidentally, the validator also threw up that you are reusing `one_0_required` as an ID for multiple elements

Comment: That did it -- looks like the problem was the extra closing DIV in openSecondary.  Thanks for spotting that!